# index, identification of object, Firebase Realtime DataSnapshot

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to optimize queries call in a live chat. To achieve that i use Firebase RealTimeData. I know that RealTime identifies every new entry by chronological ordrer. Si i try to save my chat in the device’s memory everytime a user recup queries. To  listen all changes (every New messages i put a listener query(docRef, limitToLast(1)) le méthode onChildAdded, this instructions allows me to take a snapshot of my last message. Will it  be possible to get the index, or an indentification tag of it ? So that the next call , i can Fix limitToFirst to this index to that i recup the exact same missing part.Thanks in advance and don’t hesitate to ask me questions if i haven been clair enough. Good night everyone and good cood

Comment: What do you mean by "Will it be possible to get the index"? To which index are you referring?

Comment: A property, of the Datasnapshot, for identificate my result inside the global database. In order to use it with limitToFirst method